# SQL - Function to return certain terms from a string from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query to return only certain terms from a string.

I am trying to return terms of following format within the string:

**Example: name="john doe"**

Basically, anywhere that **name="something"** in quotes, needs to only be returned.  I am trying to figure out which function or group of functions to use in order to return back in a table in a single line per row, just the instances of all the terms that show up as **name ="something"**.

Sample Table:

Column: Details

id=090001222 name="joe bob" fin alert name="sara darling"

id=090001222 name="joe bob" fin alert name="sara smith"

id=091112533 name="chris columbo" start alert

id=08995423 alert fin name="larry" print save

Comment: You should be preprocessing your JSON and normalizing your table, rather than using a complex query to parse out information.

Comment: How do I normalize the table?  Also the format above of the strings is different after the id=# part.